# PowerApp Add a Collection if OnVisible

Tags: powerapps, sharepoint-list

*I Follow a tutorial but its 1 year old and i use swedish office 365 if it makes any difference.*

https://youtu.be/wXC_SeRVEqI?t=622

I have finguere out some stuff that is different from the video.
He use **,** and it just work with **;** for me on some places.

Like this
He use. ***CollectCity*** Is just a namevariable

```
ClearCollection(CollectCity, {Result: "All"})
```

For me that is (My reference is valled ***CollectBokadAv***)

```
ClearCollection(CollectBokadAv; "All")
```

He did this code

```
ClearCollect(CollectCity, {Result: "All"});

Collect(CollectCity, Distinct(tbl_Employee,City));
```

But i get error when i use this code

[image]

the name is not valid "CollectionBokadAv" cannot be identified

[image]

***Extra if the BrowserGallery***

(When i use no distinct it become

BokadAVDropdown.Selected.BokadAv <-- Real name in the sharepointlist

BokadAVDropdown.Selected.Value <-- If i use distinct

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to understand this if you posted a single screenshot of your code, but I may be able to help.  Here are a few points:

First, ClearCollection() is not a valid function in PowerApps.  You probably meant ClearCollect().  If you just mistyped it here, then ignore this.

Second, I am aware that different regional settings can make you need to use commas or semicolons, so that is probably why you need different syntax than the YouTube video.

Third is a problem with your ClearCollect().  The second argument for ClearCollect has to be record or a table that you want to add to the collection after it is cleared.  You say that the tutorial used ClearCollect(CollectCity, (Result: "All")), but even that seems wrong.  It seems like they are trying to end up with CollectCity having a single column called Result with a single row's value being "All".  The right way to do that, though would be ClearCollect(CollectCity, {Result: "All"}).  You are entering ("All"), which is not a record or a table.  That is likely causing at least some of your problems.

Last is just a comment about Power Apps, Collections, and error messages.  I have found very strange things happen that sometimes makes the error messages unpredictable, and the behavior of collections can also be unpredictable.

- Keep in mind that when you are editing Power Apps, some of the user interface (of Power Apps) is not treating your code according to strict sequencing.  I mean that, for instance, if you enter Set(MyVariable, 0) somewhere on a certain screen, you will find that when you are editing another screen, you can reference MyVariable without throwing an error message (while editing).  When you preview your app, if MyVariable hasn't been set yet, and you try to use the value, you will get an error, but when you are just editing the app, you can reference MyVariable wherever you want without an issue.
- Specifically for Collections, this can get confusing.  In particular with columns.  If you Clear() a collection, it does not erase the column headings, it just erases the rows.  That means that, if you have ClearCollect(MyCollection, {Value: 0}) on one screen and on another screen you have ClearCollect(MyCollection, {Name: "Per"}), whenever you view your collection, it will have two columns: Name and Value.  This is related to this non-sequential idea because PowerApps sees all the places MyCollection is referenced in the app and every place records are added to it and adds whatever columns it needs to accommodate all of those.
- Here is maybe the trickiest part.  Imagine you have a collection, variable, etc., where are you are only referencing in one place.  For instance, imagine you have:

  Set(MyVar, 0);
  Notify((MyVar + 2));

You would expect to get a notification that says "2".  Imagine, though, that you start editing this code, and you start to edit the top command.  While you are editing it, in that moment, you probably are typing things.  If you pause for a moment and while you've paused the first line is no longer valid, all of a sudden, you will see an error message pop up on the lower line.  That is because, until you correct the first line, the second line is referencing a variable that is not valid.  This makes sense when you think about it, but it can lead to some confusing times if you're not paying attention.  [See this video for a demonstration of what I mean.](https://imgur.com/a/JAZt31V)

This may be happening to you.  Power Apps is telling you that "the name is not valid "CollectionBokadAv" cannot be identified", but that may only be because you have some error with it somewhere and, until you fix that, you cannot reference it anywhere successfully.  I wouldn't worry about that message necessarily.  Just make sure that, anywhere it's referenced, you fix any issues.

Comment: Isent CollectionBokadAv Created to insert values into? shouldent i be able to use - ClearCollect(CollectionBokadAv; {Result: "All"}); and get All in the dropdown?

Comment: Yes.  If you actually mean to create a one row, one column table with the column called “Result” and the single row’s value for Result be the string “All”, then yes, using the curly braces, it will do that.